# How to trim values and send to deepEquals method ()

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]){
         String [] a={"A","B"};
         String[] b ={"  B"," A"};
         Arrays.sort(a);
         Arrays.sort(b);
         System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(a,b));
}
```

I want to compare two string arrays and should return true values but its giving a false value since String[] b values has space. How do I trim my values and send to deepEquals method .

Comment: @Sotirios `static boolean isEqual(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
  for(String s : arr1) {
        if(!Stream.of(arr2).anyMatch(x -> x.trim().equals(s.trim()))) {
       return false;
        }
     }
  return arr1.length==arr2.length;
 }` Isn't cool? .. it's not mentioned in the duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

You can go through each element of the array and use the `trim` function.

```
String[] trimmedA = new String[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        trimmedA[i] = a[i].trim();
```

You can also check that the lengths of `a` and `b` are equal. If they aren't you can return false right away without sorting and trimming.

On the other hand, if you do not need to use the original strings again, you can do the trimming in place:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    a[i] = a[i].trim();
```

Comment: you don't need to create another array for that!

Comment: That would depend on whether or not you want to change the original arrays.

Comment: If you are walking through the array, you could make the comparison, also...

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto, what do you mean?

Comment: If the OP wanna use the original array items, there would be no point to compare them using trim .. because they're not equal!

Comment: Agreed. But you can do other things with the original strings after comparison. I will edit my answer to include both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `trim` function on each of the strings first.

> `public String trim()` 
>     Returns a copy of the string, with leading and
>     trailing whitespace omitted.

Something as the following should work:

```
void trimAll(String[] vec){
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++)
        vec[i] = vec[i].trim();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
         String [] a={"A","B"};
         String[] b ={"  B"," A"};
         trimAll(a);
         trimAll(b);
         Arrays.sort(a);
         Arrays.sort(b);
         System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(a,b));
}
```

[Reference here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

Answer (score 0):

Java 8's streams make this pretty neat:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String [] a={"A","B"};
    String[] b ={"  B"," A"};
    a = trimAndSort(a);
    b = trimAndSort(b);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(a,b));
}

private static String[] trimAndSort(String[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).map(String::trim).sorted().toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Note that since you're dealing with a one-dimensional array, you don't really need to use `Arrays#deepEquals`, and `Arrays#equals` would suffice.

Answer (score -1):

`trim()` doesn't match all whitespace either (it matches all characters that have a value <= space, most of which aren't technically whitespace). Therefore, this would be feasible.

```
for(int i=0;i<b.length,i++)
{
  b[i] = b.replaceAll("\\p{Z}","");
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? An explanation is essential